# jQuery deferred then fire while promise is pending

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, deferred

I've created a wrapper javascript for calls to Facebook using the Facebook Javascript SDK. During the initialization I create a promise for the current state of loading the Facebook javascript. Every public function that can make calls to the Facebook API will use this promise to ensure the SDK is available. The code looks like this:

```
function FacebookWrapper() {
    this.$sdkDfd = this.loadSDK();
}

FacebookWrapper.prototype.loadSDK = function() {
    var $deferred = $.Deferred();
    require([pathToFacebookSDK], function(response) {
        // resolve or reject deferred here
    });
    return $deferred.promise();
};

FacebookWrapper.prototype.doStuff = function() {
    this.$sdkDfd.
        then(doWhatever);
};
```

The problem is that even though the state of this.$sdkDfd is still pending doWhatever is executed anyway.
I have similar implementation around my project and they all work. Has anyone experienced then callback being fired even though the state of the promise was still pending?

Comment: If the callback is executed, the promise is no more pending. Are you sure you've passed the callback, and not accidentally called it?

Comment: If have added a interval of 10ms to log the promise state and in the console is see that is is pending. another log in the doWhatever function and another log when the promise is resolved or rejected. The console shows that state is pending, then the log from doWhatever and then that the promise is resolved.
I am also sure that I did not accidentally call doWhatever.

Comment: OK, no, I never experienced such a thing. Can you break your code down into an example that allows us to reproduce the issue, and post it here?

Comment: I am not allowed to share the original code. I tried to show the example in my question above. I am sorry for that but that are our company policies. If I write a small version for jsbin/jsfiddle it always works. I assume I spent to much time in front of the code so I dont see the forest for all the trees anymore.

Comment: We don't need the whole original code, only the part that causes the issue :-) But that it works in a plain fiddle really suggests that you're overlooking something here. Time to take a step back indeed.

Comment: @Luketep, if everything you have said is true, then I would have to guess that you are testing the state of one promise but observing the effects of another.

Comment: I found it! After the weekend I reviewed the code and found that I executed a function in the then callback instead of just passing a function. Thanks to to all of you!